React - alias in package.json crash on hooks
I need to use React lib aliased.
My package.json looks as follows
"@types/react-dom-latest": "npm:@types/react-dom@^18.2.17",
"@types/react-latest": "npm:@types/react@^18.2.37",
"react-dom-latest": "npm:react-dom@^18.2.0",
"react-latest": "npm:react@^18.2.0",

The project use the storybook, and for components which uses hooks I got following issue:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
What could be the reason?
